# Ubuntu 20:04 Novation XioSynth External USB Audio Interface producing popping & clicking sounds on playback , Alsa usb driver suspect

Tags: usb, sound, 20.04, alsa, jack

I need help troubleshooting a Novation XioSynth external usb interface running under Ubuntu 20:04. I hear popping , clicking noises on playback of an audio file . This is not the problem with Pulseaudio as the problem is still herd when bypassing pulseaudio entirely by using the APLAY command as described on https://alsa.opensrc.org/Troubleshooting. The same file was then played using the PC internal audio interface with no problems.

The problem becomes far worse when audio playback is attempted using the Jack audio server. If both the Xio input and the Xio output is selected in Jack , long bursts of static noise are herd . Exhaustively changing settings in Jack for buffer size e.t.c has no effect whatsoever.

To prove beyond doubt that the problem was not hardware related I then rebooted the same PC into Windows XP and the XioSynth played audio without problems with the Novation driver installed.

When the XioSynth is used in record mode in Ubuntu 20:04 it however works fine . This was tested using Ardour running via JackAudio . Provided the audio output (In Jack) was via the PC internal audio interface, but with the audio input from the XioSynth, It was possible to hear and record sounds played on XioSynth without problems.

#### System details

- PC Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz × 8
- Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD4 motherboard
- 12Gb ram installed
- USB descriptor ( from `/proc/asound/Xio/Stream0` )

  ```
  Novation DMS Xio at usb-0000:00:1a.1-1, full speed : USB Audio

  Playback:
    Status: Stop
    Interface 3
      Altset 1
      Format: S24_3LE
      Channels: 2
      Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
      Rates: 44100, 48000
      Bits: 24

  Capture:
    Status: Stop
    Interface 4
      Altset 1
      Format: S24_3LE
      Channels: 2
      Endpoint: 2 IN (SYNC)
      Rates: 44100, 48000
      Bits: 24
  ```

Comment: I have the same Problem with an Steinberg UR22 Interface.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298326/audio-pops-clicks-on-usb-soundcard

Answer (score 0):

Copied frome here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1298810/1155538

There are some changes being done right now in the alsa sound subsystem for usb sound cards. Your problem might be fixed in the 5.10 Kernel. Since it isn't released yet you have to wait for the kernel version to be packaged for ubuntu or compile the kernel yourself. The latter option requires quite a bit of knowledge though.