# Audio Pops & Clicks on USB-Soundcard

Tags: usb, alsa, soundcard, jack

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel Machine. When i try to playback audio on my Steinberg UR22 (Mk 1) Interface there are clicks in the audio playback. It does not matter if i use Pulseaudio, ALSA or Jack. When using Jack, the clicks/dropouts are not logged as XRUNs. The frequency of the Clicking seems to be higher respectively the clicking pulse is shorter than a regular XRUN.
I've found several places where people seem to have the same problem albeit with a diffrent sound card. All sound cards with this problem seem to be USB-Soundcards though.

I am running Kernel 5.4.0-56-generic.

The low-latency kernel and the newest kernel (5.8.0-31) also have this problem.

This is my alsa info alsa-project.org/db/?f=8b821b17a8c83fa5db866f34a5b4dfe74d640a32

Increasing the sample-size does NOT improve this problem, the clicks seem to be caused by something different than a buffer underrun, maybe caused in the driver.

This behavior wasn't present in previous versions of Ubuntu (16.04), so this seems to be a regression, maybe in the Kernel.

If this is the wrong place to ask this question I would appreciate a hint to the right channel.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pops-clicks-on-audio-interface/40129
[Ubuntu 20:04 Novation XioSynth External USB Audio Interface producing popping & clicking sounds on playback , Alsa usb driver suspect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256787/ubuntu-2004-novation-xiosynth-external-usb-audio-interface-producing-popping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some discussion on the alsa-devel mailing list this turns out to be a driver problem. This will be fixed in the future kernel release 5.11.

I don't have a real workaround besides compiling and installing a kernel from the linux-next tree right now, but that isn't a realistic solution for most people sadly.

This glitching only happens on one computer of mine tho, my laptop doesn't have this Problem at all.

One may try running the kernel module snd-usb-audio with the parameter implicit_fb=1, to try to remove the problem.

Comment: I also face alsa underruns in Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20), while Mint 19 (Ubuntu 19) was fine! I don't thing that it's a driver issue.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue 2021-05-26, and have been for a long period.  Some additional info:period of the click appears to be 5 seconds  Suspect that the the entire USB subsystem is suffering, i.e. mouse movements will skip at the same time as the audio cracks / pops.  Any further info?